# Optimizing a program for analyzing a word game

Tags: string, algorithm

I am part of the speedrunning community for a PC game called Bookworm Adventures. I have written some utilities to help people learn/practice the game. At the moment I'm trying to write something that can
analyze a game state in order to determine the best play, similar to utilities that exist for Scrabble players.

The game's board is a 4x4 square of tiles. Playing a word removes those letter tiles from the board and replaces them with randomly generated letter tiles, with a maximum of 4 of the same tile. "Qu" exists together as a single tile. (I replaced all instances of Qu with Q in the word list to simplify this) I don't know the official probabilities of each letter but I've approximated them experimentally.

The game's dictionary is loaded into memory as a tree of linked nodes. Doing this I can quickly assemble a list of valid words that are good enough to kill the current enemy. But out of those valid words I want to assess which of them leaves behind the best letters.

The way I have it now is that it generates many random board states based on those leftover letters, sums up the best scoring play from each of those boards and returns the average.

So my current flow is something like this:

```
struct word{
 string name;  // The word itself
 string leave; // The letters left behind ('?' for blank spaces)
};

vector<word> words;
// Dump all valid plays into words
int size = words.size();

for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
 word curWord = words[i];
 cout << curWord.name << ": " << leaveValue(curWord.leave);
}
```

With the function looking like

```
float leaveValue(string leave)
{
 float sum = 0;
 /*
  Here I used multithreading to split the job among all available threads.
  It helps a little bit but my computer is pretty wimpy.
 */
 for (int i=0; i<MAX_SIMS; i++)
 {
  string simBoard = randomBoard(leave); // Fills in blanks w/ random letters based on letter probability
  sum += findBest(simBoard); // Traverses the dictionary tree to find the best scoring word
 }
 return sum / MAX_SIMS;
}
```

However if I run this with MAX_SIMS = 1000 my results vary quite widely. It seems like I need at least 100k sims per word (maybe even 1M) in order to get a consistent average.

One thing I thought to do is to assemble a list of the randomized boards, only keeping unique boards but keeping track of how many times they appear. That way I'm not assessing the value of the same boards multiple times.
Is there anything else obvious I'm missing to speed this up?

EDIT: Regarding the suggestion of going through the dictionary and taking a weighted average based on the % chance of getting each word: the issue is that I only care about a word if it's specifically the highest scoring play on that board. So the % chance I would need to calculate isn't just the % chance of that word appearing, it's the % chance of it being the best word. This is a good start though.

Comment: Is the board a NxN grid of randomly places letters from which the player forms a word from some subset of these letters? If so, are  the letters used to form the word then removed and then randomly replaced with new letters? A more concise definition of the board and gameplay would be helpful -- and a well constructed example also helps. If internally you sorted the board so the letters are laid out in some systematic fashion you might be able to order the search in a more systematic way.

Comment: "However it seems like I need at least 100k sims per word (maybe even 1M) in order to get reliable results." What's a reliable result?

Comment: Instead of creating a random board, you could iterate thru the entire dictionary and compute the probability of each word occurring based on the words left over and the distribution of possible remaining letters. The probabilities would then be used a weights for the value of each word. This the result would be a weight probability over the whole space.

Comment: BTW, your question is really language agnostic and using the C++ tag is probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First scan the entire dictionary to find the highest value word that can be formed from letters in `leave`.

```
let minVal = highest value word in dictionary that can be formed by 'leave'
```

Now we scan the dictionary again but only consider words that have a value greater than `minVal`. From that we determine a weighted probability of all such words.

```
let numBlanks = 16 - length(leave)
sum_pv = 0

for word in dictionary
    if value(word) > minVal
        let letters = remove from word all letters in leave
        assert(letters not empty) // else its value <= minVal
        let p = probability(letters, numBlanks)
        let v = value(word)
        sum_pv += p*v
```

Now we determine the value of the letters left behind which can be no smaller than `minValue`:

```
leaveValue = max(minValue, sum_pv)
```

The real trick here is computing `probability(letters, n)` which computes the probability that you can get all the remaining letters with `n` blanks based on the game's probability distribution of characters. This is similar to being dealt a particular "poker hand" of `length(letters)` cards from a deck of `n` cards (repeats allowed).

I'll stop here for now in case I'm not on the right track. I should note that if the dictionary is really really large, than your Monte Carlo algorithm might be preferable.

Comment: The issue is that this is taking a weighted average of all the possible words, when it should only be worked into the average if it's the best word on the board. In other words, the probability I need for a given word needs to be the probability that I get that word AND that I don't get any of the words better than it.

Comment: @Dugongue The weighted average gives you the expected value (and I only consider words greater than the guaranteed best value). Since we don't know what new tiles will be randomly generated there is no way to know what the max word will be -- I think your Monte Carlo approach will produce the same value in the limit. I'll think about it a bit more.

Comment: @Dugongue If you want to find the highest possible score from `leave` then simply scan the dictionary and consider every word that could be *possible* from the letters remaining and all possibilities of blank values. Track the highest value encountered. Of course the probability that this could happen will be extremely low (and thus would seem useless for gameplay).